# Python Flask application is not triggering my emails on IIS Server , if there is long gap between the scheduled time

Tags: python, flask, iis, artificial-intelligence, hosting

I have a Flask application which is hosted in the IIS server and there is a mail scheduler which seems to work at first, the job runs fine every ten minutes. However, after an hour or so, it stops running. I log successes and errors, and I have no errors. What is causing my job to stop by it?

I tried searching for some solutions and i have a query.

- Do we have to create an application pool in IIS for the python app.
- or is it because of the idle time as mentioned in this blog https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1257828/Python-process-started-by-IIS-stops-running-after

Comment: My suggestion is to have a separate application pool for each application. There are many reasons for the  stop running, such as application pool settings, high memory usage, etc. Usually these problems can be found in the Event Viewer, you can try to find these errors, and then solve the problem based on these errors.

Comment: Unless this is a very busy site that all worker processes (IIS, Python ones) keep running, Windows/IIS will try to shut them down to reduce memory footprints. That likely kills your scheduler in memory. In general, run your Python apps on Linux please. There are far too many surprises unless you learn enough Windows.